# Where can I get the nsslowhash lib from for fedora 16? Source preferably

Tags: ruby, rubygems, mysql2

While trying to build the mysql2 gem with ruby 1.9.2-p320 on Fedora 16, I ran into this error,
reproducible like so:

```
gremlin:mysql2 $ cat conftest.c
    #include "ruby.h"

    /*top*/
    int main() {return 0;}
    int t() {
      void ((*volatile p)());
      p = (void ((*)()))rb_thread_blocking_region;
      return 0;
    }

gremlin:mysql2 $ gcc -o conftest -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/i686-linux \
    -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward 
    -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. 
    -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/  
    -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter 
    -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers
    -Wno-long-long conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L.  
    -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -Wl,-R -Wl,/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib 
    -lruby-static  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lnss3 -lcrypt -lm   -lc

    /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.6.3/../../../libcrypt.a(md5-crypt.o): 
    In function `__md5_crypt_r':
            (.text+0x96): undefined reference to `NSSLOW_Init'

    /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.6.3/../../../libcrypt.a(md5-crypt.o): 
    In function `__md5_crypt_r':
            (.text+0xb1): undefined reference to `NSSLOWHASH_NewContext'
```

... and many more messages for other global functions in the nsslowhash library,
which it looks like /usr/lib/libcrypt.a expects to have available, but I don't have
it installed, and can't find the source for.

Actually, that's not totally true.  I found nsslowhash as part of 
the Mozilla-Central build for Firefox, but when I run nm on the compiled
.a and .so files, none of them define anything that matches NSSLOW.
So where do these names come from?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by adding -lfreebl3 to the LIBS CONFIG setting.